# Drupal - Load CKeditor with Simplified Toolbar on dynamically created page element

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

Drupal 6 ckeditor 3.6.4

I have page that loads the text area dynamically, so I am using

```
  CKEDITOR.replace('textarea-id');
```

Which works, but it is bringing in the full toolbar. I would prefer that the simplified toolbar is used, but it would also be acceptable to use the toolbar I have defined if loading the simplified is not possible. Least desirable would be to hard-code the toolbar, but I consider that a last resort. How do I accomplish this?

I have tried

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('textarea-id',
    {
        toolbar : 'myprofile'
    });
```

Which throws js error: Type x is undefined , I think related to the fact that it cant load the profile. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better or worse, this is how I did it:

http://joe-riggs.com/blog/2012/11/drupal-ckeditor-load-configuration-settings-on-dynamic-page/